# Showing previous comments in aspx Task Form

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I am working on Custom SharePoint 2010 statemachine workflow using aspx Task forms.
Its a 3 level workflow.My scenario is 
Ex: If approver puts a comment and submits to the workflow then a task gets creaed to publisher.Then publisher opens the item thats where I wanted to show the comments from previous step.
Please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Added new field where I have stored comments when user interacts with the task.